# cakephpの暗号化復号化について

Tags: php, cakephp

以下の関数を使ってパスワードを暗号化&復号化をしたいのですが、vendorフォルダにCrypt.php
としてCryptクラスを作り、Controllerから

```
App::uses('Crypt', 'Vendor');
```

を呼び出しても、Securityクラスが見つかりませんとなってしまいます。
どのようにすればうまくいきますでしょうか。

```
class Crypt {
    static public function encrypt($text) {
        return base64_encode(Security::rijndael($text, Configure::read('constants.crypt_key'), 'encrypt'));
    }

    static public function decrypt($text) {
        return Security::rijndael(base64_decode($text), Configure::read('constants.crypt_key'), 'decrypt');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

CryptがSecurityクラスに依存しているので

Crypt.phpのクラス定義の前に

`App::uses('Security', 'Utility');`

を追記してください。

Comment: また、このCryptクラスはアプリケーションに依存しているようですので、`Vendor`よりも`Lib`に配置する方が適切かもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

コントローラ内でコンポーネントを定義してみたらいかがでしょうか。

> public  $components = [ 'Security' ];